# python3 login website tumblr.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

How can I log in tumblr using requests in python3?
Here is my code but it dosn't work well and go back to the login page.
I used request.post to post a log-in form data, and failed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url = 'https://www.tumblr.com'

# set a session for request
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0', 'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;'}
                 )

# get the form_key for login_in
r = s.get(start_url)
login_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
hidden_div = login_soup.find('div', class_='form_row_hidden').find_all('input')
key_dict = {}

for input_tag in hidden_div:
    tmp_dict = input_tag.attrs
    key_dict.update({tmp_dict['name']: tmp_dict['value']})

user_data_dict = {'determine_email': '×××××××××',
                  'user[email]': '××××××××',
                  'user[password]': '××××××××',
                  'user[age]': '',
                  'tumblelog[name]': ''}

key_dict.update(user_data_dict）


# log in tumblr
r_login=s.post(start_url, headers=headers, data=key_dict)

home_soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(home_soup)
# the output is still the log-in page.
```

Comment: what is your exception? why don't use [pytumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr) API lib?

Comment: Can I just use requests to log in tumblr rather than using API?

Comment: you can. 1st you have to make a get request to tumblr.com/login with user agent set up like you did. In result of this request, you have to parse and get `form_key` value, this value is used to make a real post to login. After you got `form_key`, include it in your `key_dict` and make a post. To make sure you're logged in, make a get request to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/get_post_form_builder_data to confirm.

Comment: I added sample code below

Answer (score 5):

You're nearly to target.

Firstly, you have to make a request to tumblr login page (https://tumblr.com/login). (You did)

Then, you have to parse html page and get `form_key` value. This value is used to make a real login.

Finally, make a post request, with the payload:

```
{'user[email]': your_mail,
'user[password]': your_pass,
'form_key': form_key
}
```

Below is sample code in python 2, but I'm not using `BeautifulSoup` ( you asked to use `requests` only ;)

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from lxml import html

In [3]: url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/login'

In [4]: ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'

In [5]: headers = {'User-Agent': ua}

In [6]: s = requests.session()

In [7]: lg = s.post(url, headers=headers)

In [8]: lg_html = html.fromstring(str(lg.text))

In [9]: form_key = lg_html.xpath("//meta[@name='tumblr-form-key']/@content")[0]

In [10]: payload = {'user[email]': 'your_mail',
   ....:            'user[password]': 'your_pass',
   ....:            'form_key': form_key}

In [11]: # real login

In [12]: s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
Out[12]: <Response [200]>

In [13]: print s.get('https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/get_post_form_builder_data').text
{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"channels":[{"name":"your_name","tags":[]}],"limits":{"videoSecondsRemaining":300,"preuploadPhotoUsed":0,"preuploadAudioUsed":0,"inlineEmbedsPerPost":5}}}
```

Comment: Please include a full answer, don't just reference a comment. As it is right now, this isn't really an answer

Comment: Why is this not an answer? OP asked how to use `requests` to login tumblr, and my code does that.

Comment: You should explain it a bit more. Include what you said in your comment, just describe how it works.